# AMPScript dynamic value for UpsertData function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I'm trying to set a variable dynamically to `UpsertData` function via Cloud Page form submission, but haven't been able to get it working so far.

The attribute name from Data Extension is the dynamic value here, to which I would be posting a static value.

```
%%[ VAR @skey, @Type
SET @skey = RequestParameter("skey")
SET @Type = RequestParameter("Type")

IF Not Empty(@skey) THEN
UpsertData("MyDataExtension", 1,
"ID", @skey,
"@Type", "Accepted"
)
ENDIF]%%
```

I've tried setting the Data Extension attribute name in various ways, but no dice so far.

Examples that don't work :

```
"%%=v(@Type)=%%", "Accepted"
```

And

```
"TreatAsContent(%%=v(@Type)=%%)", "Accepted"
```

Has anyone worked with a similar scenario or knows if this is even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to output the value using the `v`-Function in order to achieve that. As you are already within an AMPscript-Block, you don't need the starting and ending codes `%%=` and `=%%`. This code will work:

```vb
%%[
    VAR @skey, @Type
    SET @skey = RequestParameter("skey")
    SET @Type = RequestParameter("Type")

    IF Not Empty(@skey) THEN
        UpsertData("MyDataExtension", 1, "ID", @skey, v(@Type), "Accepted")
    ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After four hours of trying everything .. it was that simple. Much appreciated!

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help! ;)